# ValueError: too many values to unpack-converting pkl file to unpack

Tags: python, neural-network

I am running the code to train multi class and im getting the error too many values to unpack using the yelp dataset python DNN for sentiment analysis.

```
(reviews_words_index, labels) = pickle.load(open("review_sents_1859888.pkl", 'rb'))
```

but i get en error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read anything on tuple-unpacking, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479776/too-many-values-to-unpack-exception).

So in your case, do:

```
my_data = pickle.load(open("review_sents_1859888.pkl", 'rb'))
print(len(my_data))
# e.g. 4
```

Then you can unpack this with the right number of variables on the left:

```
a, b, c, d = pickle.load(open("review_sents_1859888.pkl", 'rb'))
```

So it basically seems that this object is not exactly setup like you expect it to be!

Comment: Hi Thanx for your reply, when i am trying to find the length i got the value '1013951'  and i got the following error                                                                         IndexError: index -2147483649 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5