# trying to grab all column values that aren't equal to 0.000000 in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

I have a dataset shown below and I am trying to grab each name in the feature column where the importance column is not equal to 0.000000 and put them straight into a list to use straight away. I have tried a few methods but the main two which show promise are as follows:

### Method 1

```
new_features = []

for i in importance_ranking['importance']:
    if i > 0.000000:
        new_features.append(i)
        
new_features
```

method 1 just grabs me all of the values of the importance column, but I want the feature column value instead so I tried method 2

### Method 2

```
features_to_use = []
for x,y in importance_ranking:
    if y > 0.000000:
        features_to_use.append(x)
        
features_to_use
```

method 2 throws me the error as follows:

### method 2 error

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1181-d1ec4f141ff9> in <module>()
      1 features_to_use = []
----> 2 for x,y in importance_ranking:
      3     if y > 0.000000:
      4         features_to_use.append(x)
      5 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

any help is greatly appreciated

### method 3 and error

```
    features_to_use = []
for s,x,y in importance_ranking:
    if y > 0.000000:
        features_to_use.append(x)

features_to_use
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1182-8ed92369130e> in <module>()
      1 features_to_use = []
----> 2 for s,x,y in importance_ranking:
      3     if y > 0.000000:
      4         features_to_use.append(x)
      5 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

### Dataset

```
   **feature    importance**
1   src_bytes   0.541433
18  count   0.160338
30  dst_host_diff_srv_rate  0.074743
53  service_bgp 0.066960
31  dst_host_same_src_port_rate 0.045040
28  dst_host_srv_count  0.027176
9   num_compromised 0.016684
25  diff_srv_rate   0.008991
58  service_pm_dump 0.008533
62  service_auth    0.008270
29  dst_host_same_srv_rate  0.006760
2   dst_bytes   0.005153
33  dst_host_serror_rate    0.004642
6   hot 0.003985
32  dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate 0.003330
35  dst_host_rerror_rate    0.002923
34  dst_host_srv_serror_rate    0.002222
87  service_klogin  0.002135
116 flag_SH 0.001553
0   duration    0.001263
7   num_failed_logins   0.001125
22  rerror_rate 0.001011
27  dst_host_count  0.000917
4   wrong_fragment  0.000736
52  service_ntp_u   0.000489
37  flag_RSTOS0 0.000468
3   land    0.000449
111 service_tftp_u  0.000355
19  srv_count   0.000289
8   logged_in   0.000284
... ... ...
16  is_host_login   0.000000
40  service_Z39_50  0.000000
41  service_http_443    0.000000
43  service_other   0.000000
44  protocol_type_tcp   0.000000
45  service_link    0.000000
46  service_X11 0.000000
47  service_exec    0.000000
48  service_red_i   0.000000
49  service_http_2784   0.000000
```

### Line used to create Dataframe

```
importance_ranking = pd.DataFrame({'feature':all_cols, 'importance':dt.feature_importances_})
```

### pic of dataframe

[image]

### new_test

```
#features_to_use = []
a,b = importance_ranking[0]
#for s,x,y in importance_ranking:
 #   if y > 0.000000:
     #   features_to_use.append(x)
#
#features_to_use


KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2524             try:
-> 2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1244-5d9e2e614219> in <module>()
      1 #features_to_use = []
----> 2 a,b = importance_ranking[0]
      3 #for s,x,y in importance_ranking:
      4  #   if y > 0.000000:
      5      #   features_to_use.append(x)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2137             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2138         else:
-> 2139             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2144         # get column
   2145         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2146             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2147 
   2148         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1840         res = cache.get(item)
   1841         if res is None:
-> 1842             values = self._data.get(item)
   1843             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1844             cache[item] = res

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3841 
   3842             if not isna(item):
-> 3843                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3844             else:
   3845                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:
-> 2527                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2528 
   2529         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Is that first column with numbers a part of the file? Looks like you have 3 values in each row, so unpacking into two would throw an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Too many values to unpack" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479776/too-many-values-to-unpack-exception)

Comment: @kabanus yes i think it is, I have tried using method 2 with 3 values in the for statement but still doesnt work

Comment: Then post that attempt and the error as well. In particular, you only want the last two columns, so something like `_,a,b` looks like it would work.

Comment: @kabanus ive added the new attempt as method 3

Comment: Looks like the line is still something your not expecting. Clearly there are more than 3 items in the line. I suggest you print the first line to debug this, see what is actually contained `importance_ranking`. I'm not sure if you are using a `dict` or a `dataframe`, but check the shape of your data.

Comment: @kabanus ive added the line of code used to create the dataframe and a pic of the dataframe

Comment: Well that is strange. Looks good. What does `importance_ranking[0]` right before the offending loop show you? Try unpacking that before the loop (e.g. `a,b = importance_ranking[0]`), and if that work, print `x,y` in the loop and see if it's a specific offending row somehow (no idea how).

Comment: @kabanus  didnt work im afraid, added test error to end of post

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice it was `pandas` - you can remove that, it's irrelevant. Print the first line. My point is, try and see what you are iterating - maybe don't unpack, and just `for a in ...` - and print in the loop to see what you're getting. You have the best chance of finding the error yourself I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrames offer a great way to select the data you want

```
features_to_use = importance_ranking[importance_ranking['importance'] > 0.0]['importance'].values.tolist()
```

It may be difficult to understand at a first sight but what you actually do is filter all the importance_rankings that have an importance greater than 0.0 and then select the importance column of the importance_rankings that satisfy this condition. The rest of the line `.values.tolist()` is just used to unpack your data.

If you feel uncomfortable with this solution you can just try doing it step by step:

```
df = importance_ranking[importance_ranking['importance'] > 0.0] # Filtered Dataframe
importance_values = df['importance'] # Series Object
features_to_use = importance_values.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best idea is to use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = importance_ranking[importance_ranking['importance']>0.000000]
```

and then get features:

```
features = df.features
```