# Maximal matching between two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching

Suppose we have two dataframes.

original_data

| sequence_number | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10.42 |
| 2 | b | 1.27 |
| 3 | b | 6.32 |
| 4 | a | 5.91 |

jumbled_data

| sequence_number | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | b | 6.43 |
| 12 | b | 1.26 |
| 13 | a | 9.98 |
| 14 | a | 15.84 |
| 15 | a | 6.01 |

Then I want to perform a matching on this data so that I end up with a 1-1 correspondence between them. Where the matching maximises the size of the matching and minimises the difference in fuzzy_criteria. I.e the matching would be

| sequence_number_original | fuzzy_criteria_original | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria_jumbled | sequence_number_jumbled | fuzz_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.42 | a | 9.98 | 13 | 0.44 |
| 2 | 1.27 | b | 1.26 | 12 | 0.01 |
| 3 | 6.32 | b | 6.43 | 11 | 0.11 |
| 4 | 5.91 | a | 6.01 | 15 | 0.1 |

**EDIT:**

To highlight the need for a maximal matching consider the following example:

original_data

| sequence_number | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |

jumbled_data

| sequence_number | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | a | 1.9 |
| 14 | a | 2.9 |

Then a matching would provide (sorted by minimal diff):

| sequence_number_original | fuzzy_criteria_original | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria_jumbled | sequence_number_jumbled | fuzz_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | a | 1.9 | 13 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 1 | a | 1.9 | 13 | 0.9 |
| 2 | 2 | a | 2.9 | 14 | 0.9 |
| 1 | 1 | a | 2.9 | 14 | 1.9 |

then removing duplicates in sequence_number_original would provide the following

| sequence_number_original | fuzzy_criteria_original | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria_jumbled | sequence_number_jumbled | fuzz_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | a | 1.9 | 13 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 1 | a | 1.9 | 13 | 0.9 |

then in sequence_number_jumbled

| sequence_number_original | fuzzy_criteria_original | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria_jumbled | sequence_number_jumbled | fuzz_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | a | 1.9 | 13 | 0.1 |

Equally the other way round would do the same. First sequence_number_jumbled ...

| sequence_number_original | fuzzy_criteria_original | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria_jumbled | sequence_number_jumbled | fuzz_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | a | 1.9 | 13 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 2 | a | 2.9 | 14 | 0.9 |

Then sequence_number_original...

| sequence_number_original | fuzzy_criteria_original | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria_jumbled | sequence_number_jumbled | fuzz_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | a | 1.9 | 13 | 0.1 |

However this is not maximal as there is the following:

| sequence_number_original | fuzzy_criteria_original | fixed_criteria | fuzzy_criteria_jumbled | sequence_number_jumbled | fuzz_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | 1.9 | 13 | 0.9 |
| 2 | 2 | a | 2.9 | 14 | 0.9 |

There are maximal matching algorithms in graph theory. I did actually just see [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329474/how-to-get-the-most-pairs-out-of-my-pandas-dataframe) that is similar to mine.

Comment: You can consider this as "join 2 dataframes with `fixed_criteria` and drop duplicates of `sequence_number_original` by keeping only the minimum `fuzz_diff`".

Comment: Thanks @Emma, you are right. The trouble is with the second part of your statement. How would you do this? To me it isn't trivial as you could do this for each sequence_number_original then sequence_number_jumbled however you may get rid of connections that were valid but just not as good as the minimal match on the left or the right.

Comment: Do you need to drop by just `sequence_number_original`? (`sort_values(['sequence_number_original', 'fuzz_diff').drop_duplicates(['sequence_number_original'])`)  In your example, I see unique `sequence_number_original` is reserved but `sequence_number_jumbled` is whatever matching the criteria.

Comment: Thanks @Emma I just edited the question to be a little clearer on this point. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is largely copied from @SpghttCd answer to [How to get the most pairs out of my pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329474/how-to-get-the-most-pairs-out-of-my-pandas-dataframe)

The idea is to use networkx to perform a maximal matching.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

# Data input

original_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'sequence_number' : [1,2,3,4],
    'fixed_criteria' : ['a','b','b','a'],
    'fuzzy_criteria' : [10.42, 1.27, 6.32, 5.91]
})

jumbled_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'sequence_number' : [11,12,13,14,15],
    'fixed_criteria' : ['b','b','a','a','a'],
    'fuzzy_criteria' : [6.43, 1.26, 9.98, 15.84, 6.01]
})

# Merge along fixed criteria

joined_data = pd.merge(
    original_data,
    jumbled_data,
    how = 'inner',
    on = ['fixed_criteria'],
    suffixes=['_original','_jumbled']
)

# To use max weight, take the reciricol of the difference (if they are the non-
# unique values this will have to be changed)

joined_data['weight'] = (1/abs(
    joined_data['fuzzy_criteria_original'] -
    joined_data['fuzzy_criteria_jumbled']
))

# Form graph

matching_graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    joined_data,
    source = 'sequence_number_original',
    target = 'sequence_number_jumbled',
    edge_attr = 'weight'
)

# Find matching

mathing = nx.max_weight_matching(
    matching_graph,
    weight = 'weight'
)

# Convert results back into dataframe and format

results = pd.DataFrame(
    list(mathing),
    columns=['sequence_number_original', 'sequence_number_jumbled']
)

results = pd.merge(
    results,
    joined_data,
    how = 'inner',
    on = ['sequence_number_original', 'sequence_number_jumbled'],
)

results['fuzzy_difference'] = abs(
    results['fuzzy_criteria_original'] -
    results['fuzzy_criteria_jumbled']
)

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no duplicated values on both `fuzzy_criteria` columns. You can create an auxiliary dataframe to determine the nearest value between two `fuzzy_criteria` columns.

```py
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(product(original_data['fuzzy_criteria'], jumbled_data['fuzzy_criteria']), key=lambda t: abs(t[0]-t[1])))
df = df.drop_duplicates(0, keep='first')
df = df.drop_duplicates(1, keep='first')
```

```
print(df)

       0     1
0   1.27  1.26
1   5.91  6.01
2   6.32  6.43
4  10.42  9.98
```

Then use this auxiliary dataframe to merge these two dataframe separately and finally merge the merged dataframes based on auxiliary dataframe columns.

```py
df_ = pd.merge(
    (pd.merge(original_data, df, left_on='fuzzy_criteria', right_on=0)),
    (pd.merge(df, jumbled_data, left_on=1, right_on='fuzzy_criteria')),
    on=[0,1],
    suffixes=('_original', '_jumbled')
).drop([0, 1], axis=1)
df_['fuzz_diff'] = (df_['fuzzy_criteria_original'] - df_['fuzzy_criteria_jumbled']).abs()
```

```
   sequence_number_original fixed_criteria_original  fuzzy_criteria_original  \
0                         1                       a                    10.42
1                         2                       b                     1.27
2                         3                       b                     6.32
3                         4                       a                     5.91

   sequence_number_jumbled fixed_criteria_jumbled  fuzzy_criteria_jumbled  \
0                       13                      a                    9.98
1                       12                      b                    1.26
2                       11                      b                    6.43
3                       15                      a                    6.01

   fuzz_diff
0       0.44
1       0.01
2       0.11
3       0.10
```

Comment: Hi @Ynjxsjmh thanks for the answer. The issue is keeping the duplicates with minimal weighting might reduce the size of the pairing. Please see me edited question for a clarification.