# Value error while accessing 10,000 .png image files from a folder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a large data of about 10,000 images using the vgg16 pre-trained network for this i coded this but it seems to generate

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).

path= "C:/Users/52/.spyder-py3/IAM/train_patches/*.png"

(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test) = path   //The error is occurring here
```

initially when i was just using  it simply it was working but now when i'm using datagen function its not working. Please kindly help me in making this code correct

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.applications import VGG16
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import keras
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import optimizers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


seed=10
np.random.seed(seed)

path= "C:/Users/52/.spyder-py3/IAM/train_patches/*.png"

(X_train,y_train) == path   //The error is occurring here
sample_image = X_train[1,:,:,:]
plt.imshow(sample_image), plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
classes = 651
Y_train = to_categorical(y_train,classes)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')


X_train = X_train/255


img_rows, img_cols = 500,500
channels=3

#Include_top=False, Does not load the last two fully connected layers which act as the classifier.
#We are just loading the convolutional layers. 
vgg_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,3))

# freeze the layer except the last 4 layers
for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable=False
num_classes=10
model = Sequential() 
# Add the vgg convolutional base model
model.add(vgg_conv) 
# Add new layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
 # Show a summary of the model. Check the number of trainable parameters
model.summary()    
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40,
                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                             height_shift_range=0.2,
                             zoom_range=0.2,   
                             horizontal_flip=True,
                             fill_mode='nearest')

datagen.fit(X_train)

print("Size is: ",X_train.shape[0])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#generator=datagen.flow(datagen.flow(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=128))

history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=128),
                              steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0]/128,
                              epochs = 2,
                              verbose=1)
acc = history.history['acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
epochs = range(len(acc)) 
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'b', label='Training acc')
plt.title('Training accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
model_json = model.to_json()
open('C:/Users/52/.spyder-py3/IAM/imdata.json','w').write(model_json)
model.save_weights('C:/Users/52/.spyder-py3/IAM/imdata.h5',overwrite=True)
```

Comment: You really need to read [mcve], two lines would have been enough to demonstrate your problem. Also, reconsider your question's title thereafter. As new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask] as well. Oh, and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479776/too-many-values-to-unpack-exception?r=SearchResults&s=1|290.6034. That's the first hit when just searching the error message.

Comment: You have a big conceptual misunderstanding, the line that produces your error makes no sense, you need a function that loads the data and makes a train/test split

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you're trying to make an assignment on 4 variables, but the function to thr right of the `=` only outputs two.
I think it's beacuse you're reading the data and labels and also making training/testing split.

Try to read all the images and labels in only two variables and then make the split.

Comment: im not spliting the data in test or train this code is simply to train and generate model