# API Request - ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests

I'm trying to collect some data from the website https://seminovos.unidas.com.br/ using it's api. However, my code returns back an error like:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Could you guys help me with that, please?

Here follows the code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import requests as rq
 import warnings
 from datetime import date
 warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
 from email.mime.text import MIMEText
 import smtplib, ssl
 import win32com.client as win32

 session = rq.Session()
 headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
           'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive',
           'Content-Length': '425',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
           'Cookie': 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InR6aWFkdmt0TkN1cmljcXFnSzhjWlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTjQzQWpBUENDQ2JVT3JzbDI5MStKNURCOGJMTUs0K3dkOWpRRTJuOHY2NFd5ODlOYk4yMTZuenhaTktBZ29TNyIsIm1hYyI6ImI3NjQzNjE4NjliZTM3NzdlYjI4ZDYxMDA5NTgxODY1MWEzODE4ZDYwZDRkNjMzYzg4NzcxZDEzNjA5ZWM2ZTIifQ%3D%3D; unidas_session=eyJpdiI6IkZVK0p5ZG0wcHI1VEFZWGtBeVdkcnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiekFlQjNOSmxcL1ZDeHdGVHlMbGpXYjZ3RG1aQ0k0NjRLMXpFTG5hRTJZbTlWemo0MkhDUEhCV1djMlBvSWtsMHAiLCJtYWMiOiJkYzZlMGIxMzIzMmI0MzY3YjFiZmJlNWUxNzc2ZGNmZTFlOGYzNmJiNzYyY2Q4YjgzMTBmYTY1NTM2MGIyMDhhIn0%3D',
           'dnt': '1',
           'Host': 'seminovos.unidas.com.br',
           'Origin': 'https://seminovos.unidas.com.br',
           'Referer': 'https://seminovos.unidas.com.br/veiculos',
           'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
           'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
           'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Mobile Safari/537.36',
           'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'eyJpdiI6InR6aWFkdmt0TkN1cmljcXFnSzhjWlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTjQzQWpBUENDQ2JVT3JzbDI5MStKNURCOGJMTUs0K3dkOWpRRTJuOHY2NFd5ODlOYk4yMTZuenhaTktBZ29TNyIsIm1hYyI6ImI3NjQzNjE4NjliZTM3NzdlYjI4ZDYxMDA5NTgxODY1MWEzODE4ZDYwZDRkNjMzYzg4NzcxZDEzNjA5ZWM2ZTIifQ==',    
}
params = {'page':'1'}

 response = session.post('https://seminovos.unidas.com.br//json/veiculos.json?page=1',headers=headers,params = params, verify = False)
```

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting a bit. Don't use backticks for long pieces of code. The main issue now is there's an extra space on each line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too many values to unpack" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479776/too-many-values-to-unpack-exception)

Comment: Please include more detailed stack trace for the error you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Make params a dict, like `params = {"page": 1}`.

Answer (score 0):

params is a tuple within a tuple, You might change:

```
params = (('page','1'))
```

to:

```
 params = ('page','1')
```

which now has two values.