# why/ ValueError : too many values to unpack

Tags: python

**Error:**

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
in this line
FORM_CLASS, = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "main.ui"))
```

Can someone explain why?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

import os
from os import path
import sys

FORM_CLASS, = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "main.ui"))

class MainApp(QMainWindow , FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainApp,self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: just print and see the output of this `loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "main.ui"))` you will know why you getting error

Comment: `loadUiType()` returns 2 values, you're expecting single.

Comment: If you wish to ignore the second value, the usual idiom is `FORM_CLASS, _ = ....` and forget about the `_` variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too many values to unpack" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479776/too-many-values-to-unpack-exception)