# How to fix ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) in Python?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I have a dataset called `records`, a dataset sample looks like:

```
user_id movie_id genre
1       1001     action
2       1002     drama
3       1003     comedy
4       1004     drama
...     ...      ...
```

I would like to iterate over `records` in the following way:

```
for user, movie, genre in records:
    print(user, movie, genre)
```

It first prints some rows and then shows this error:

```
44892 113769 comedy
44892 113769 drama
...  
------------------------------------------------ 
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) in 
----> 1 for user, movie, genre in records:
      2     print(user, movie, genre)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: On some iteration your `records` variable must have more than 3 elements. Maybe you could discard any surplus using `for user, movie, genre in records[:3]:`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your dataset. There might be some rows where data is seperated by tab and it's considering the row as new column. because of which the error is getting thrown.

Example :

userid  movieid      genre

44892    113769   horror comedy

here, if you've selected separator as tab/space then it'll consider the horror & comedy as different column.

or you can refer :
["Too many values to unpack" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479776/too-many-values-to-unpack-exception)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but I cant add a code snippet. Hence adding as an answer

```
for item in records:
    print(item)
    user, movie, genre=item
```

You'll have your value of the record printed just before the code breaks via ValueError.

Once you show us at what record the failure occured, it will be easier to get a solution

Note. If you want to ignore a record which doesnt match expected pattern, you can do

```
for item in records:
    try:
        user, movie, genre=item
    except ValueError:
        print("Failed at %s" % repr(item))
    else:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your dataset loaded as a pandas dataframe? if yes you can do something like this

```
cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'genre']
# Assuming df is the data frame you have
for ind in df.index:
  user_id, movie_id, genre = df.loc[ind, cols]
  print(user_id, movie_id, genre)
```

If you don't have column names in the dataset, perhaps adding them yourself is a valid step ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to discard any extra data being returned

```
for user, movie, genre,*_ in records:
    print(user, movie, genre)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your variable names are different:

You called them `user_id`, `movie_id`, and `genre` in the dataset, but refeered to them as `user` and `movie` subsequently.

Try changing it to:

```
for user_id, movie_id, genre in records:
    print(user_id, movie_id, genre)
```

Comment: actually I don't have the column names in the original dataset, I wrote them here for clarity. Anyway it doesn't explain why code works for some rows (prints some rows) and suddenly gives an error.