# Preparing Nova Compute entries while open stack installation [ERROR]

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I was installing `openstack` but not able to pack the answer file, Please help me with the solution   .

```
 [root@xcatmaster ~]#  packstack --answer-file=/root/abc.txt
    Welcome to the Packstack setup utility
```

The installation log file is available at: `/var/tmp/packstack/20210919-002228-8TVYUo/openstack-setup.log`

```
    Installing:
    Clean Up                                             [ DONE ]
    Discovering ip protocol version                      [ DONE ]
    Setting up ssh keys                                  [ DONE ]
    Preparing servers                                    [ DONE ]
    Pre installing Puppet and discovering hosts' details [ DONE ]
    Preparing pre-install entries                        [ DONE ]
    Setting up CACERT                                    [ DONE ]
    Preparing AMQP entries                               [ DONE ]
    Preparing MariaDB entries                            [ DONE ]
    Fixing Keystone LDAP config parameters to be undef if empty[ DONE ]
    Preparing Keystone entries                           [ DONE ]
    Preparing Glance entries                             [ DONE ]
    Checking if the Cinder server has a cinder-volumes vg[ DONE ]
    Preparing Cinder entries                             [ DONE ]
    Preparing Nova API entries                           [ DONE ]
    Creating ssh keys for Nova migration                 [ DONE ]
    Gathering ssh host keys for Nova migration           [ DONE ]
    Preparing Nova Compute entries                    [ ERROR ]
    ERROR : too many values to unpack
    Please check log file /var/tmp/packstack/20210919-002228-8TVYUo/openstack-setup.log for more information
    Additional information:
     * Parameter CONFIG_NEUTRON_L2_AGENT: You have chosen OVN Neutron backend. Note that this backend does not support the VPNaaS or FWaaS services. Geneve will be used as the encapsulation method for tenant networks
     * Time synchronization installation was skipped. Please note that unsynchronized time on server instances might be problem for some OpenStack components.
```

Help me with the solution i tried to setup in all ways!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the true **ERROR** tips: `ERROR : too many values to unpack`.

I don't know about `packstack`, but from here ["Too many values to unpack" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479776/too-many-values-to-unpack-exception), it seems that the parameter items in your **answer-file** get out the same number of configure file which `packstack` need.

One more thing, I think you should fixed this warning: `Time synchronization installation was skipped.` Before deploy `openstack` environment, we should synchronize the time between nodes at first.