# 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 10)'

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working on a self-learning project on AIS ship tracking, and the following line of code:

```
hi_boat1,hi_boat2,hi_boat3,hi_boat4,hi_boat5,hi_boat6,hi_boat7,hi_boat8,hi_boat9,hi_boat10 = [x for _, x in hi_eez.groupby(hi_eez['mmsi'])]
```

is giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 10)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please provide your code (or an example that produces the same error).

Comment: At first glance i'd guess that your list comprehension returns a list of length > 10.
But yeah like @CrazyEngineer said a full example would help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error says that the code on the right-hand side of the expression should return a list with 10 objects as you use ten variables on the left hand side for unpacking that list.

see ["Too many values to unpack" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479776/too-many-values-to-unpack-exception?rq=1)

e.g. `a,b,c,d,e,f,g = [x for x in range(7)]` works while `a,b,c,d,e,f,g = [x for x in range(8)]` throws `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 7)`

you should state what you are trying to achieve and maybe add the desired output. so, you could for example assign that list to a variable and then further process it.

```py
my_list = [x for _, x in hi_eez.groupby(hi_eez['mmsi'])]

for elem in my_list:
    print(elem)
```